# Using a different service account in Cloud Build

Tags: google-cloud-build, google-iam

I can't use the preview feature to add a different service account, but I do have the physical key (.json). I've uploaded this key to Secrets Manager and I intend to call it in during the build.

Is what I have done correct?

```yaml
steps:
  - id: 'Setup Credentials'
    name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    entrypoint: '/bin/bash'
    secretEnv: ['SERVICE_ACCOUNT']
    args:
    - '-c'
    - |
      echo "$$SERVICE_ACCOUNT" >> /credentials/service_account.json
    volumes:
    - name: 'credentials'
      path: /credentials

availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
  - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/service-account-key/versions/latest
    env: 'SERVICE_ACCOUNT'
```

Then in a step that needs to use it I am overwriting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`:

```yaml
  - id: 'Do stuff as other service account'
    name: 'hashicorp/terraform'
    entrypoint: '/bin/bash'
    args:
    - '-c'
    - |
      GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/credentials/service_account.json
      # do things here
      # terraform plan
    volumes:
    - name: 'credentials'
      path: /credentials
```

Ideally we would use this cloud builds service account but they already have too much going with the other one.

Comment: 2 questions: Why you can't use the preview feature? Why do you not use impersonation?

Comment: They have a "master" service account that is already added to all the other projects for managing infrastructure deployments. So they want to use it instead of moving to cloudbuilds one. I also can't seem to add that service account in the preview feature even when given the correct permissions.

Comment: Ok, do you mean that the service account key file is used by al the other projects? And thus you have the secret key of something super powerful? Wow, and nobody is scared? Anyway, despite the security concern, what you are doing is correct

Comment: Yes the key is a massive concern. I've come in to try and help. Previously they were running everything in one project. I'm hoping that buy moving the key away from the end users into Secrets Manager its a first step to show them they don't need to take the sledgehammer approach.

Comment: Understood. It was my fight for 2 years in my previous company!!